# Parsing rows of information from html using python

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I wanted to find a way to parse information from:

```
<tr>
   <td class="prodSpecAtribute">Rulebook Chapter</td>
   <td colspan="5">
     <a href="http://cmegroup.com/rulebook/CME/V/450/452/452.pdf" target="_blank" title="CME Chapter 452">CME Chapter 452</a>
   </td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td class="prodSpecAtribute" rowspan="2">
      Trading Hours
      <br>
      (All times listed are Central Time)
   </td>
   <td>OPEN OUTCRY</td>
   <td colspan="4">
      <div class="font_black Large_div_td">MON-FRI: 7:20 a.m. - 2:00 p.m.</div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>CME GLOBEX</td>  #PROBLEM HERER -- WANT this and  div below to be one row, considered under class <td class="prodSpecAtribute" rowspan="2"> ... Trading Hours... 

   <td colspan="4">
      <div class="font_black Large_div_td">SUN - FRI: 5:00 p.m. - 4:00 p.m. CT</div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I was able to parse information in the top table easily as follows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
left_col = soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class' : 'prodSpecAtribute'})
right_col= soup.findAll('td', colspan=['4', '5'])
```

So in this example there are 3 rows:
2 have `class "prodSpecAtribute"` and atleast one column corresponding to each class.
However, the last row, has *no class*, so I need a way to use the last class and define this new under the same class, along with the 2 of the third row's `<td>`s: `CME GLOBEX and SUN - FRI: 5:00 p.m. - 4:00 p.m. CT`

#### Combine_column method:

```
def combine_col(right):
    num = len(right)

    for i in range(0, num):
        text_ = ' '.join(right[i].findAll(text=True))
        print text_

    return text_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way to merge the second and third columns of the second row is to iterate over the rows explicitly. Anything you write with `find_all` is just going to return row0-col1, row1-col1, and row1-col2 as three separate values, and you'll have no way of knowing which ones go together.

So, if I understand your problem, you want something like this:

```
left_col = []
right_col = []
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    left, right = tds[0], tds[1:]
    assert('prodSpecAtribute' in left['class'])
    left_col.append(left)
    right_col.append(combine_columns(right))
```

Except that you need to write that `combine_columns` code, because I don't know how you want to "combine the information" in the columns.

I'm obviously using the rule that column 0 goes in the left, rather than whatever column has class `prodSpecAttribute`. I did this mainly because I can't figure out what you'd want to happen for a row that had no such column, or where it wasn't the leftmost column. So, I just added an `assert` for sanity checking, to verify that this is always the right rule for your source.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by combine was to append the texts the found in `tds[0] tds[1] ...`

Comment: Could you take a look at the post again, I forgot to add the last `<tr>` which is difficult to figure out

Comment: You really need to give a much less vague description if you want more exact answers. Or, better, instead of describing what you want, just show the exact output you want.